# Commit of undefined in nuxt vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

```
<script>
  computed: {
    loggedOut () {
      return this.$store.state.login.logged
    }
  },
  signin (store) {
      this.$auth.loginWith('local', {...code}
      }).then(this.$store.commit.login('login/LOGGED_IN')) // <- error in commit
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

i retrieve loggedOut() computed property but when i try to mutate it by commiting it, it gives me an error:

**[vuex] unknown mutation type: login/LOGGED_IN**

My login.js file:

```
export const state = () => ({
  logged: false
})

export const mutations = () => ({
  LOGGED_IN (state) {
    state.logged = true
  },
  LOGGED_OUT (state) {
    state.logged = false
  }
})
```

index.js file:

```
export const state = () => ({
})

export const mutations = {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be work

```
this.$store.commit('login/LOGGED_IN')
```

Because Nuxt.js default store/xxx.js (each .js file except index.js) is one module, so you need use module way to call it

see https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode

your `login.js` mutations syntax is wrong, nuxt.js has different syntax, please look [demo](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/vuex-store)

```
export const mutations = {
  LOGGED_IN (state) {
    state.logged = true
  },
  LOGGED_OUT (state) {
    state.logged = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried this aswell but i get this error: "[vuex] unknown mutation type: login/LOGGED_IN"